# I can't get the session value to print

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<script language="javascript" >
    function addSelection(){
        var tst="hello";
        sessionStorage.setItem("test", tst);
        <% 
            String pastst=request.getParameter("tst");
            session.setAttribute("tst1",pastst); 
        %> 
        addSelection1();
    }
    function addSelection1(){
        var outtst = '<%= session.getAttribute("tst1") %>';
        <%
            out.print("session"+session.getAttribute("tst1"));
        %>
        var tstout= session.getAttribute("tstout");
        alert(tstout);
    }
</script>
```

`alert(tstout);` works properly, but the code inside jsp prints blank.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the purpose behind this. Anyway few issues found in your code.

First. You cannot get the javascript variable value like this,

```
   var tst="hello";   //Setting the value in javascript
   sessionStorage.setItem("test", tst);
   <% 
       String pastst=request.getParameter("tst");  //Expecting the value will be returned by java request
       session.setAttribute("tst1",pastst); 
   %>
```

Second. Following line will provide you JS error, You cannot assign like this `var tstout= session.getAttribute("tstout");`

You need to change into, `var tstout= '<% session.getAttribute("tstout"); %>'`

Its wrong assumption javascript will print the session value in the following line,

```
<%
   out.print("session"+session.getAttribute("tst1"));
%>
```

Finally, you need to start learning [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) and [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) avoid using scriptlets.

This is the way some where it is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function addSelection(){
    var tst="hello";
    sessionStorage.setItem("test", tst);
    <% 
        String pastst="hello";
        session.setAttribute("tst1",pastst); 
    %> 
    addSelection1();
}
function addSelection1(){
    var outtst = '<%= session.getAttribute("tst1") %>';
    alert('<%
        out.print("session : "+session.getAttribute("tst1"));
    %>');
    alert(outtst);
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thans you Vinoth Krishnan

Comment: You are welcome. Mark this as accepted answer if you find it useful, since others still can get benefits from that.